# Создать yandex maps как объект

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Скажите, я могу создать yandex maps как объект, без привязки его в DOM?
В конечном счете мне нужно получить текущие координаты пользователя в фоновом режиме.
Чтобы пользователь ничего не видел и не нажимал.
Использую angular.
Как-то так.
new Maps().getPosition();

Comment: Думаю это будет нарушением 3-го пункта правил https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/terms/index-docpage/

Comment: А что мне делать, если есть случаи когда мне нужно пользователю показывать карту ?

Comment: Очевидно, что при желании обойти условия бесплатного использования необходимо перейти на коммерческую лицензию. Либо пойти на уступки и добавить-таки карту на страницу, раз используете возможности сервиса - сделать хотя бы разворачиваемый блок с картой и явную кнопку/ссылку на его открытие, поскольку на карте же ещё и копирайты со ссылкой на пользовательское соглашение размещены, которые также необходимо отображать.

Answer (score 0):

По идее мою задачу можно решить так.
Взял пример их песочницы яндекс карт.  https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/geolocation
Только нужно закомментировать создание карты.

```
ymaps.ready(init);


    geolocation.get({
        provider: 'browser',
        mapStateAutoApply: true
    }).then(function (result) {
        // Синим цветом пометим положение, полученное через браузер.
        // Если браузер не поддерживает эту функциональность, метка не будет добавлена на карту.
        result.geoObjects.options.set('preset', 'islands#blueCircleIcon');
      //  myMap.geoObjects.add(result.geoObjects);
    });
}
```